# Using $.getJSON to perform cross domain request problem

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, json, cross-domain

I'm using the following code to make cross domain request using $.getJSON, request completed but with errors, I cannot exactly detect what is the thrown error.

Based on callback param of request value I route it to a certain method which retrieves required JSON data.

```
$.getJSON("http://wthsrvr:45452/Handler.ashx/?Callback=DocumentReadStatus",
  {
      userID: vuserID,
      documentID: vdocumentID,
      format: "json"
  },
  function(result) {
      if (result.readStatus == '1') {
          alert("ACCEPTED");
      }
      else if (result.readStatus == '0') {
          alert("NOT ACCEPTED");
      }
      else {
          alert(result.readStatus);
      }
  });
```

FYI: while development of this locally, everything worked fine, but after solution deployment to server and trying to do the same, I got that problem.

Also, I tried the same functionality with web service, I got the same problem while calling web service from server.

I'm using ajaxSetup to detect thrown errors.

```
$.ajaxSetup({ "error": function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("textStatus: " + textStatus);
    alert("errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
    alert("responseText: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
 } 
});
```

Comment: @ahmed did you see firebug net panel ?? what error is is throwing , looks like you are running to cross domain issue here

Comment: @gov: firebug request completed with status code 200, and response was empty, but I got the error from $.ajaxSetup({ "error" ...

Comment: @Ahmed: What is the response you normally get? Is the server generating JSONP ? Because you only send `format: 'json'` to the server...

Comment: @ahmed , whats happening if you are typing the url directly on the browser..??

Comment: @gov: if you put the url in browser, file save dialog comes up.

Comment: @fleix: I return Json data format {\"readStatus\": \"" + readStatus + "\"}

Comment: @ahmed...open that in notepad and see the results...

Comment: @gov: I got the following json {"readStatus": "Document Reference Number must be greater than zero.User ID is required."} which is actually returns from my code, so what is the problem?

Comment: @gov: what are the modifications required in my call to catch this response?

Comment: @ahmed looks like your server side is throwing some exception , send some response to the UI if you have any exceptions at the backend

Comment: @gov: I did, stilling getting error from $.ajaxSetup and empty response (firebug). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access across different website, you have to use JSONP, which actually becomes a request of a JavaScript file and the data is sent back as part of the JavaScript file.

Comment: For JSONP, shall you provide a sample for how to use it? Or how to convert the above calling to be JSONP?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it was a permission issue. Using "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" HTTP header so that the resource can be accessed by any domain in a cross-site manner.

Check the following [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control) for this.

Comment: Yes, you cannot make cross-domain calls. It should have worked if you used JSONP properly.